# React Native. Navigate to SignIn/SignUp screen if user is not authenticated

Tags: react-native, navigation

I'm designing a tabbed app. When the application is started it checks whether a user is authenticated and if he is it renders application main tabs but in case he is not SignIn screen should be rendered. SignIn is not a tab but a separate screen. It has a "Sign up" button which must open SignUp screen. When on SignUp screen "back" button is pressed SignIn screen is opened.

It seems to me that I have to compound StackNavigator with TabNavigator but I don't know how that is done.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class SignIn extends Component {    
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>SignIn screen</Text>
            </View>
        );
    };
}

class SignUp extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>SignUp screen</Text>
            </View>
        );
    };
}

class TabOne extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "TabOne"
    };
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>This is tab One</Text>
            </View>
        );
    };
}

class TabTwo extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "TabTwo"
    };
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>This is tab Two</Text>
            </View>
        );
    };
}

const TabApp = TabNavigator({
    First: { screen: TabOne },
    Second: { screen: TabTwo }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TabApp', () => TabApp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ex-navigation I am doing that like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {

    render() {

        if (!isLoggedIn) {
            return (
                <NavigationProvider router={Router}>
                    <StackNavigation
                        initialRoute={Router.getRoute('sign')}
                    />
                </NavigationProvider>);
        }

        return (
            <NavigationProvider router={Router}>
                <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
                <TabScreen />
            </NavigationProvider>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Your-App-Name', () => App);
```

When you are done with signing you can go to tab screen (in this case I remove the navigation history):

```
this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetStack([Router.getRoute('tabScreen')]);
```

And my TabScreen is the main screens with tabs. That's it.

```
render() {
        return (
            <TabNavigation
                id="main"
                navigatorUID="main"
                initialTab="home"
            >
                <TabItem
                    id="home"
                    title="Home"
                    renderTitle={this.renderTitle}
                    renderIcon={this.renderIcon}
                >
                    <StackNavigation
                        id="home"
                        navigatorUID="home"
                        initialRoute={Router.getRoute('home')}
                    />
                </TabItem>

                <TabItem
                    id="info"
                    title="Info"
                    renderTitle={this.renderTitle}
                    renderIcon={this.renderIcon}
                >
                    <StackNavigation
                        id="info"
                        initialRoute={Router.getRoute('info')}
                    />
                </TabItem>

                <TabItem
                    id="profile"
                    title="Profile"
                    renderTitle={this.renderTitle}
                    renderIcon={this.renderIcon}
                >
                    <StackNavigation
                        id="profile"
                        initialRoute={Router.getRoute('profile')}
                    />
                </TabItem>
            </TabNavigation>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I know how that is done with `ex-navigation`. I just want to implement this with the newest library as `ex-navigation` is not developed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more level to your navigation stack

Example:

```
const MyTabsNavigator = TabNavigator({
    First: { screen: TabOne },
    Second: { screen: TabTwo }
});

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  MyTabs: { 
    screen: MyTabsNavigator,
  },
  SignIn: { 
    screen: SignIn,
  },
});
```